# How to create multiple selectors using list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I initially had a Drop-down working using list items instead of select tag.

The initial html looked like this:

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
  allOptions.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
  allOptions.toggle();

  console.log($('.selected .value').text());
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:not(.init) {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li:not(.init):hover,
ul li.selected:not(.init) {
  background: #09f;
}

li.init {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a#submit {
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drowpdown-one">
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Man Uni</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I make it work for multiple dropdowns?

I did it in my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111) but its does not work properly as you can see if you run such.

The values just mess around.

Comment: Multi-Level Dropdowns 
https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: @Shital Marakana. The link goes a completely different topic. Please load my snippet to see functionality. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To acccomplish this you would need to use all relative selectors:

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
  ul = $(this).closest("ul");
  lis = ul.find("li:not(.init)").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  ul.children('.init').html($(this).html());
  lis.toggle();

  console.log($('.selected .value').text());
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:not(.init) {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul li:not(.init):hover,
ul li.selected:not(.init) {
  background: #09f;
}

li.init {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a#submit {
  z-index: 1;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drowpdown-one">
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Man Uni</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Man Uni</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @WosleyAlarico You're welcome, If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Are you still for a help on the same matter?
Hope you dont mind updating your answer according to my snippet: https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Not super sure what you're referring to there.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the two lists by the item you clicked on.

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});


$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    var allOptions = $(this).parents('ul').children('li:not(.init)');
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('ul').children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
    console.log($('.selected .value').text());
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:30px;
}
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }

li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
li, ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drowpdown-one">
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Man Uni</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="drowpdown-one">
  <ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Man Uni</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then a widget like this is best phrased as a jQuery plugin.

You might write something like this for example ...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.dropdownWidget = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $ul = $(this);
            if($ul.filter('ul').length == 0) {
                return true; // continue
            }
            var $init = $ul.children('.init').on('click', function() {
                $allOptions.toggle();
            });
            var $allOptions = $ul.children('li').not($init).on('click', function() {
                var $li = $(this);
                var selectedIndex = $allOptions.filter('.selected').index();
                $allOptions.removeClass('selected').toggle();
                $li.addClass('selected');
                $init.html($(this).html());
                if(selectedIndex !== $li.index()) { // trigger `change` event only if there was a change.
                    $ul.trigger('change', {
                        'element': $li,
                        'value': $li.data('value'),
                        'textValue': $li.find('.value').text(),
                        'numbers': $li.find('.numbers').text(),
                        'text': $li.text(),
                        'selectedIndex': $li.index() - 1 // index not counting .init, therefore `- 1`
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

... allowing you, not only to initialise two or more independent widgets, but also to mimic standard HTML dropdown behaviour by which a 'change' event is emitted, and thus avoid the need to hard-code the `console.log(...)` (or whatever) in the widget code.

```
$('#myContainer ul').dropdownWidget().on('change', function(event, data) {
    console.log([data.value, data.textValue, data.numbers].join(', '));
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kwb7s9ap/)**

Or maybe this more generalized version, in which the widget code is simplified and extraction of text from the two spans is performed in the `change` handler.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kwb7s9ap/1/)**

Comment: It seems to be very reusable. Appreciate the support

Comment: If you ever need dropdowns with different actions, you will have to do something at least something like this. With the action embedded in the widget code, you will end up having to repeat large chunks.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the jquery since my scripting skills is still new. Do you mind making it work as per my snippet classes? Here is what I have: https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111

Comment: I *could* but please remember this is a help service, not a free code writing service. My plugin implements your original paradigm, tidied up but otherwise unchanged, and relies on your original CSS. If you change class names then you will need to adjust the CSS and the plugin.